# How to reduce the size of label for the plot of random error of LME model?

Tags: r

I tried to extract the random effect of my LME model with ranef and plot it. But the y-axis has too many levels and thus the labels are all crammed together. Is there a way to reduce the size of the labels or plot only part of the graph?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZSPQ.png)

I used this code to obtain the figure.

```
x<-ranef(Model, condVar=TRUE)
plot(x)
```

This is how the data looks like.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFJj2.png)

Comment: Hey, can you show the code you did to obtain the figure and maybe part of the data so wan can more more properly help you

Comment: Hi, I have added the code and data now. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, from where is coming the ranef function